# How to get maven project running local server from IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jetty

Early stages of understanding Java development. I have created a new Maven project in IntelliJ (not used an archetype).

So far I have added a folder called src/main/webapp and dropped an index.jsp file in there that has some sample code that prints "hello world" to the screen.

I then examined some example pom.xml files and attempted to create my own that would allow me to at least run my app locally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>romac</groupId>
    <artifactId>connect-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>romac-connect</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8005</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I'm then unsure how to run my project with Jetty or with Google Cloud Tools. I'm developing for Google App Engine Standard so which is preferable for using as local server? how do I get it to run from IntelliJ UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are developing for App Engine standard, you are correct to use [Google Cloud Tools for IntelliJ](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij), which provides an App Engine specific local dev server. Please try the following:

First ensure you are running the latest version of the plugin: **18.6.1** (as of this writing). You can verify this in the plugin manager under `Settings -> Plugins -> Google Cloud Tools`.

In your `src/main/webapp` directory, create a `WEB-INF` folder if there is not one already. Inside of that folder, create a file named `appengine-web.xml` (the configuration file needed for App Engine standard apps). Populate that file with the following starter xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

After doing this, the plugin should detect that you are working with an App Engine standard project and pop up a Framework Support addition menu - accept the prompt. If you don't see it, you can go to `Tools -> Google Cloud Tools -> Add App Engine Support -> App Engine standard` and select your module.

After this, the local-run and deployment run configurations should be created for you allowing you to run and debug your app locally, and then deploy it to GCP App Engine.

Note that there will be a release coming soon that will fix auto-generation of the app engine config file for Maven and Gradle projects (via the tools menu mentioned above). This would allow you to skip the manual steps. For now you should be able to do it manually as desribed above.

Comment: What an excellent answer!! Thank you on all levels. As you suggest was missing these two files in WEB-INF folder. Reason is I had created my Maven project without using any archetype and didn't have the files from the beginning. I created new project using webapp archetype, then added support for App Engine standard form Google Cloud Tools plugin and all worked when I hit the play button! :)